# Get a random event out of a set of mutually exclusive events

Tags: python, random

> #### Task:
>
> Get a random event from a set of collectively exhaustive and mutually
>   exclusive events, with this set being represented by a list of tuples
>   `(name, probability)`.
>
> #### Reminder:
>
> - Collectively exhaustive events means at least one of them must occur.
> - Mutually exclusive events means at most 1 of them occurs.
> - Collectively exhaustive and mutually exclusive means their probabilities sum up to 1 and only one of them occurs.

#### Code:

Events definition:

```
events = [
    ('Win', 0.5),
    ('Loss', 0.3),
    ('Draw', 0.2)
]
```

Getting the random event:

```
def get_random_event(events):
    random_number = uniform(0., 1.)
    lower_bound = 0
    for event, prob in events:
        if lower_bound <= random_number <= lower_bound + prob:
            return event
        else:
            lower_bound += prob
```

#### Illustration:

```
0 -- -- Win -- -- 0.5 -- Loss -- 0.8 - Draw - 1
```

Generate a random number in `[0,1]` and check where it falls.

Comment: This only works because of the ordering of the data in `events` , which isn't very obvious. Do you have a check that ensures that it's ordered in by `prob`?

Comment: Order does not matter at all here. @Ben

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some things:

1. The collectively exhaustive events are not going to change or be updated. So use a tuple instead of a list:

   ```
   events = (  # <<- Note: ( not [ 
       ('Win', 50),
       ...
   )
   ```
2. You don't show your import of `random`. But I'd prefer that you not import `uniform` by name, and rather spell it out inside your function. You're only calling it once, so it's more efficient to the reader for you to simply say:

   ```
   random_number = random.uniform(...)
   ```

   than to have them search backwards for where `uniform` occurs. Also, of course, in this context `random.uniform` actually reads better than just `uniform`.
3. You have an input parameter `events`. You use `event, prob` in your loop. But `event` is the singular of `events`, so when you say `return event` it seems like you are returning a member of the `events` iterable. I'd choose a different name, like `outcome`, making it clear that your returning a *component* of the inner tuple.
4. You compare `lower_bound <= random_number <= lower_bound + prob` but you don't have to. Since your random number is pinned to 0., you could just use a comparison against the high value and get the same result.
5. Structurally, the `lower_bound += prob` shouldn't be in the `else` branch. Yes, it only executes when the `if` is not executed, but the `if` should not be part of the flow for that statement. I'd rather see:

   ```
   if ...
       return ...

   lower_bound += prob
   ```

   This kind of thing comes back to bite you when you're refactoring. Or, worse yet, when someone else is refactoring. (Imagine you changed the `return` to a `print`, or something. Suddenly the code stops working.)
6. The **Task** description would (almost) make a good function docblock. Note: s/list/iterable/:

   ```
   from typing import Iterable, Tuple

   Name = str
   Prob = float

   def get_random_event(events: Iterable[Tuple[Name, Prob]]) -> Name:
       """Get a random event from a set of collectively exhaustive 
       and mutually exclusive events, with this set being represented
       by an iterable of tuples (name, probability). 

       """
   ```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a recent version of Python (3.6+), the behaviour you're seeking is already implemented in [`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices).

Basically, all you need to do is to split the `event` list of couples into two lists and feed these two lists to the `choices` function. `zip` is there for you:

```
def get_random_event(events):
    event, = random.choices(*zip(*events))
    return event
```

Comment: @Graipher I thought it was pretty obvious from the docs, but added it in the answer anyway.

Comment: Yes, but I had to click the link first :). Did not know about this new function until now, this is a nice addition to the `random` module.

Comment: Can I import this function, somehow, to Python 2.7 ?

Comment: @AdelRedjimi you might be able to use the implementation [from the standard library](https://bitbucket.org/mirror/cpython/raw/4243df51fe43e47419713d3d490ace342097514a/Lib/random.py)